# It is possible to pack a c structure with bit fields in php?

Tags: php, c, struct, binary, bit

Hello guys i have this C structure and i want to know if is possible to pack it in php fpr writing into a binary file:

The struct in C is:

```
struct Date
{
  unsigned spare : 6;
  unsigned day : 6;
  unsigned month : 4;
  unsigned year : 16
};
```

I read the docs in perl which php copied to implement binary pack and see that you can pack structs but no example for struct with bitfields

Any ideas for generating in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by adding a custom extension to php:

```
PHP_FUNCTION(custom_pack)
{
    long ts;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "l", &ts ) == FAILURE) {
        RETURN_NULL();
    }

 time_t t = ts;

   struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);

   struct MariaDBColmunStoreDateTime the_date;
   the_date.msecond = 000000;
   the_date.second = tm.tm_sec ;
   the_date.minute = tm.tm_min;
   the_date.hour = tm.tm_hour;
   the_date.day = tm.tm_mday;
   the_date.month = tm.tm_mon + 1;
   the_date.year =  tm.tm_year + 1900;


   char str[16];

   sprintf(str,"%016llx",the_date);

   strcpy(str, str_reverse_in_place(str,16));                

    RETURN_STRING(str, 1);
```

}